# Gitlab-runner run python2 instead of python 3

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

here is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: python:3.6

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/lint.sh
    - ./scripts/lint.sh
    - chmod +x ./scripts/tests.sh
    - ./scripts/tests.sh
```

Note that on my local machine, the job is running without any problem and it is using `python 3.6.13`

Running the job test online, I got this error: It does not make any sense!

below is the config of the runner which can run untagged job and the error message.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot you've showed, the job is run using the `shell-executor`, and so is using the Python version on whichever machine you have installed the `gitlab-runner` on.

It looks like you want to use the `docker-executor` for using `image: python:3.6`, and so I would reinstall the runner to use the [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html).

Alternatively, you can update your machine which is using the shell executor, to have Python 3 instead.

Another issue could be that you have not tagged your runners, and are using the wrong `gitlab-runner`. Make sure you've tagged your shell / docker runners, ie with `shell-runner` or `docker-runner`, and then in the `test` job, add:

```
tags:
  - docker-runner
```

Comment: the same file was working last week! It is all about gitlab-runner

Comment: afraid I can't really comment more without more info @BetterEnglish. Maybe you installed a new runner? either way, if you have more than 1 runner, you should use tags!

Comment: Thanks but I have only 1 runner for 1 project.

Comment: Ok, either update your runner to use the docker-executor, or upgrade Python on the shell-runner.